# How to set a default value for a new profile property for existing users in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I added a new boolean property to my profile class.

I can't seem to find a way however to have it's value be true by default.

```
Profile.ShowDocumentsNotApplicable
```

returns false when not explicitly set to true...

web.config contents:

```
<!-- snip -->
<profile inherits="Company.Product.CustomerProfile">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<!-- snap -->
```

CustomerProfile:

```
public class CustomerProfile: ProfileBase
{
    private bool _showDocumentsNotApplicable = true;

    public bool ShowDocumentsNotApplicable
    {
        get { return Return("ShowDocumentsNotApplicable", _showDocumentsNotApplicable); }
        set { Set("ShowDocumentsNotApplicable", value, () => _showDocumentsNotApplicable = value); }
    }

    private T Return<T>(string propertyName, T defaultValue)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)base[propertyName];
        }
        catch (SettingsPropertyNotFoundException)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    private void Set<T>(string propertyName, T setValue, System.Action defaultAction)
    {
        try
        {
            base[propertyName] = setValue;
        }
        catch (SettingsPropertyNotFoundException)
        {
            defaultAction();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With boolean properties, you'll often find they can be expressed either way round. I consider it best practice to have them whichever way makes "false" the default. So, if by default you want `Profile.ShowDocumentsNotApplicable` to be true, then I'd call it `Profile.HideDocumentsNotApplicable`, for which the default is false. The reasoning behind this is that the compiler sets uninitialised bools to false; it makes sense to have your logic's defaults matching the compiler's defaults.

If the reverse is less suited (for example, you're always using `!Profile.HideDocumentsNotApplicable` and you find this reduces readability) then you could do the following:

```
public class CustomerProfile: ProfileBase
{
    private bool _hideDocumentsNotApplicable;
    public bool ShowDocumentsNotApplicable
    {
        get { return !_hideDocumentsNotApplicable); }
        set { _hideDocumentsNotApplicable = !value); }
    }

    //other stuff...
}
```